# Enabling Field Service Lightning on Developer

Tags: field-service-lightning

I'm trying to enable Field Service Lightning within a Developer Edition.  The posts I've seen refer to contacting Salesforce if you have a paid edition, but there seems to be no answer when trying to enable from Developer.

If I go to the Field Service Settings, I only see `Enable Work Orders`, and nothing else.

**Can Field Service Lightning be enabled within a Developer Edition org? If so, how?**

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are asking exactly. I have enabled Field Services in a developer org without the issue you describe. Please add more information what you did in order to achieve what.

Answer (score 1):

We can enable Field Services Lightning in a developer org. Since the user licenses are limited - you cannot simulate all actors in FSL.

In your case - Make sure "Enable Work Orders" is checked and give a try.

Share the screenshot for further debugging.

refer :-https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fs_enable.htm&type=5